# Change parent in xml by Python (lxml)

Tags: python, xml, parsing, lxml

Hi I am parsing and completely modifying XML file in Python3 using lxml and I need put new Element into existing Elements and change their parent.

Example:
old xml

```
<a>
  <b>something</b>
  <c>something different</c>
</a>
```

new xml

```
<a>
  <new_parent>
    <b>something</b>
    <c>something different</c>
  </new_parent>
<a>
```

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a function that do directly what you want. I would do it as follow: Create a `new_parent` node and append children of `a` to `new_parent` node, and append `new_parent` to `a`.

```
import lxml.etree

xml = '''<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ASCII'?>
<root>
  <a>
    <b>something</b>
    <c>something different</c>
  </a>
</root>'''

root = lxml.etree.fromstring(xml)
a = root.find('.//a')
parent = lxml.etree.Element('new_parent')
for child in a:
    parent.append(child)
a.append(parent)

print lxml.etree.tostring(root, xml_declaration=True)
```

prints (output format is modified to make it easy to read)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ASCII'?>
<root>
  <a>
    <new_parent>
      <b>something</b>
      <c>something different</c>
    </new_parent>
  </a>
</root>
```

**UPDATE** You can use `extend` instead of multiple calls of `append`.

```
root = lxml.etree.fromstring(xml)
a = root.find('.//a')
parent = lxml.etree.Element('new_parent')
parent.extend(a)
a.append(parent)
```

Comment: Downvoters: How can I improve the answer? If you have more good way to solve the problem, please post it.